# Swift AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction scale

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have the following code to change the scale,rotation, and size of a video i'm loading in via AVURLAsset. WHen i complie and run the code, it works fine.

But, if the image is front facing camera, I want to be able to flip the video left or right so that the users face doesnt look backwards....

You can see my code here:

```
    let layerInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: videoTrack)

    let rotation: CGAffineTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI_2))
    let translateToCenter: CGAffineTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(videoSize.height, 0)
    let mixedTransform: CGAffineTransform = CGAffineTransformConcat(rotation, translateToCenter)

    //CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, 1)
    layerInstruction.setTransform(mixedTransform, atTime: kCMTimeZero)
```

You can see in my code that I have commented out the CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, 1).

My question is how can I add CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, 1) to my code to make the image appear to have flipped horizontally.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
t = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1.0, 1.0);
t = CGAffineTransformTranslate(t, -videoSize.height, 0);
t = CGAffineTransformRotate(t, (90 * CGFloat(M_PI) / 180.0));
t = CGAffineTransformTranslate(t, 0.0, -videoSize.height);
```